# How to make WebView editable on winrt?

Tags: webview, winrt-xaml

I need to create simple HTML editor. I know desktop application I can get access to DOM and set DesignMode=true. How can I do it for WebView in winrt application?

Answer (score 0):

So seems I've found solution how to set DesignMode for WebView in WinRT applications.

I just needed invoke javascript method that could change document.designMode property to "on"

In my case I implemented extension for WebView where added DependencyProperty.

```
public static class WebViewEx
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DesignModeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                                               "DesignMode", typeof(bool),
                                                                               typeof(WebViewEx),
                                                                               new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDesignModePropertyChanged));

    private async static void OnDesignModePropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            return;

        WebView view = dependencyObject as WebView;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue == e.OldValue)
            return;

        await view.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                await view.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.designMode = \"on\";" });
            }
            else
            {
                await view.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.designMode = \"off\";" });
            }
        });
    }

    public static void SetDesignMode(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DesignModeProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetDesignMode(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(DesignModeProperty);
    }
}
```

That allows me to turn on\off DesignMode from XAML

```
<WebView x:Name="webViewBody" Source="about:blank" controls:WebViewEx.DesignMode="true"/>
```

Mandatory requirement to Invoke javascript methods is webview should be initialized. In my case I set source property to "about:blank"